# Which touchpad driver is being used?

Tags: drivers, touchpad

Im running ubuntu on a dell vostro, and I want to configure some trackpad settings. When I run 'xinput --list' I see two touchpad drivers:

⎜   ↳ DELL08CF:00 04F3:30C3 Touchpad            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]

⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]

The first one is a synaptics driver, and the second one is libinput. How do I find out which one is being used in my system?

Answer (score 0):

You can find this out by running

```
xinput list-props 11 && xinput list-props 15
```

But both devices will use the same driver unless you deliberately change it.

You can try to disable one or another by

```
xinput disable 11
```

or

```
xinput disable 15
```

to see which is really used.

I think it is the same device but with PS/2 and i2c interfaces.